# Problems with angularfire in ASP.NET Core , Angular project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angularfire

I was following this tutorial to work with angular-fire with the goal to include notifications https://itnext.io/push-notification-with-angular-net-core-a2280d18eda1 but I am reviving error described by the error message:

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,74): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
>         node_modules/@angular/fire/messaging/messaging.d.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'

package.json content

```
  "name": "BeLiveWebApp",<br>
  "version": "0.0.0",<br>
  "license": "MIT",<br>
  "scripts": {<br>
    "ng": "ng",<br>
    "start": "ng serve ",<br>
    "build": "ng build ",<br>
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",<br>
    "test": "ng test",<br>
    "lint": "ng lint",<br>
    "e2e": "ng e2e"<br>
  },<br>
  "private": true,<br>
  "dependencies": {<br>
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",<br>
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",<br>
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",<br>
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",<br>
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",<br>
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",<br>
    "cropperjs": "^1.4.0",<br>
    "firebase": "^7.6.1",<br>
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",<br>
    "ngx-mask": "^2.4.4",<br>
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",<br>
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",<br>
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"<br>
  },
  "devDependencies": {<br>
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",<br>
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",<br>
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",<br>
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",<br>
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",<br>
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",<br>
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",<br>
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",<br>
    "karma": "~2.0.0",<br>
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",<br>
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",<br>
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",<br>
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",<br>
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",<br>
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",<br>
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",<br>
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"<br>
  }<br>
}
```

Any idea how to overcome this.

```
Visual Studio 2019
Win 10
```

Comment: What version of angular you are using?

Comment: I had include entire content of package,json to my question, This way it will be more useful.

Comment: As it's happening inside the packages, I would try deleting the `node_modules` folder and then use terminal command `npm i` to reinstall them.